# Run .exe file automatically on booting (or better alternative)

Tags: windows, boot, hotkeys

My problem: by default the `Fn` + `F10`/`F11`/`F12` hotkeys on my ASUS laptop don't work by default.

After a lot of Googling I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3g11KVe_d8) with a solution: I have to navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ATK Package\ATK Hotkey` and run `HControl.exe`. After doing so, all hotkeys seem to work fine.

However, after rebooting my laptop I have to do this again. Is there any elegant way to **avoid having to rerun this file** after each reboot? Perhaps run it automatically on starting up or something? How would one typically fix this?

I should add to this that I may have caused to problem myself by "decrapifying" my laptop a bit too rigorously, but I can't confirm that.

**Update 1: I'm on Windows 8**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way: drop shortcut to that file in StartUp folder. You didn't specify your version of Windows, but if you enter `cd "%allusersprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"` in Command prompt you should jump to the right location.

More advanced way: run Regedit, go to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, add new string value named `HControl` (or any other of your choice), and assign to it full path to `HControl.exe`.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I could put a shortcut to the file on the desktop as well I guess. However, that's just not as "automatic" as I'd like it. Do you feel the Windows Registry solution is preferable over the task scheduler and -if so- why?

Comment: No, not on Desktop, but in Startup! Startup is special system folder: all shortcuts (or any executable file) placed there are running automatically when user logs in.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant the start *menu*. So that gives me three options: 1) Task scheduler 2) Startup folder 3) Windows Registry. Any reason to prefer any of these?

Comment: It seems to me that dropping one shortcut in one folder (and even add value in registry) is much more simple than dig into long and wordy TaskSched wizards, so you'll achieve the same result doing less. But you definitely should use way which is more convenient  for **you** ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7). You can configure it to run on boot, or on logon which may be better in your case.

Comment: It's only worthwhile doing this if the program you're trying to run triggers UAC and you don't want to have to confirm every time it runs. Otherwise putting it in the startup folder is quicker and easier.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem as you. The keyboard lights and mousepad `fn` buttons were not working and running `HControl.exe` would make it work. The solution for me was enabling the service `ASLDR Service` from ASUS that was disabled.

To enable it:

- Click `Windows` + `R`
- Type `msconfig` and press enter
- Enable `ASLDR Service` and click `Apply`